# SQL friend function

Tags: sql

What would be the best way to structure a friend "function". 
This is what im thinking:
Lets say I have a usertable with the following columns: user_id, username, password...
and a table by the name of friends with columns: friend1, friend2, accepted.

If user2 adds user1 I want user2 to be shown on user1's profile and user1 on user2's...:O

this seems a little messy...is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE (friend_id_a, friend_id_b, accepted)
```

Define a constraint: `friend_id_a < friend_id_b`.

Populate the table with your entities as follows:

```
INSERT
INTO friend_friend(friend_id_a, friend_id_b)
VALUES (LEAST(@id1, @id2), GREATEST(@id1, @id2))
```

To select all friends of a person:

```
SELECT friend_id_b
FROM friend_friend
WHERE friend_id_a = @id
 AND accepted
UNION ALL
SELECT friend_id_a
FROM friend_friend
WHERE friend_id_b = @id
 AND accepted
```

UNION ALL here lets you use indexes and avoid extra sorting for uniqueness.

All above is valid for "friendness" as a symmetric and anti-reflexive relationship. That means that:

- If **a** is friend to **b**, then
  **b** is friend to **a**
- **a** is never a friend to **a**

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is good. The second table `friends`  (primary key `friend1`, `friend2`), where a row `f1`, `f2` is present if "friendship between `f1` and `f2` is about to be established", and `accepted` is True if it has actually been established, is the right way to represent a many-to-many relation.

(The only issue with the naive approach is  when you must *check* that `f1` is a friend of `f2`'s: It may mean that the row `f1`, `f2` is present, *or* that the row `f2`, `f1` is. +1 to Quassnoi for overcoming this difficulty.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you mean a massive table with a column for each friend, or two tables like below, but the latter is best.

```
[dbo].[Users]{
    User_ID int,
    UserName VarChar,
    Password ...
}

[dbo].[Friends]{
    User1_ID int,
    User2_ID int,
    Accepted bit
}
```